# Stuck on my code due to arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 different problems that I need help with in this code, the first is in convertToFah. I need to use the array in the constructor and convert each double using the formula for converting to Fahrenheit (Centigrade (the double value) * 9.0/5.0 + 32) and return it (I always get an error like can't convert from double to double[] when I try.). The second is that I have to set maxMonth/minMonth to whatever month is in the same index as the max/min value. (So if the max is 10 and it is at array[3] then the month would be April). Any help would be wonderful. (BTW I simply haven't gotten to toString yet so that isn't really a problem at the moment.)

```
public class Temp {
private String [] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

public Temp (){
    double array[],avg = 0, max = 0, min = 0;
    String maxMonth= null, minMonth = null;
    }
public double convertToFah(double array[]){
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++){

    }
}
public double calAvg(double avg, double array[]){
     double sum = 0.0;

     for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++){
              sum = sum + array[index];
     }

     return avg = sum /array.length;

}
public double findMin(double array[], double min, String minMonth){
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] < min){
            min = array[index];
        }
    }

    return min;
}
public double findMax(double array[], double max, String maxMonth){
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] > max){
            max = array[index];
            return max;
        }
    }

    return max;

}
```

}

Comment: "I have 2 different problems that I need help with in this code" - please ask about *one* problem per post, and include only code relevant to that problem - edit your post to include a [mcve] for just that one problem.

Comment: And please actually ask a question.  "I need _X_" is not a question.

Comment: You seem to be confused about arguments and return values. For example, in your method calAvg, the method takes an array of values as input (argument), and is supposed to compute the average of these values as output (return value). Why does it take an average value as argument? Also, what is convertToFah supposed to do with its argument, and what is it supposed to return. My advice: write the javadoc of the methods before you even start implementing them. Desribe what every argument is, and what the method returns.

Comment: you're not stuck due to arrays. arrays can't do that

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of `public double convertToFah(double array[])` to `double[]` because you are going to return a double array of temperature converted to Fahrenheit.

```
public double[] convertToFah(double array[]) // returns double array
```

Now if you want to get the month with max/min temperature then modify your `findMin` & `findMax` methods to return the `index` of max/min temperature, then you can use that `index` to find the `month`.

```
public int findMin(double array[], double min, String minMonth){
    int min_index = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] < min){
            min = array[index];
            min_index = index;
        }
    }
    return min_index;
}
```

Same for `findMax` ...

```
public int findMax(double array[], double max, String maxMonth){
    int max_index = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] < max){
            max = array[index];
            max_index = index;
        }
    }
    return max_index;
}
```

then you can do like `minMonth = months[findMin(array, min, minMonth)];` to get the min month.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your second question is, but I assume your first one is to convert the temperature and store it back to the array. Try the following code:

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++){
    array[index] = array[index] * 9.0/5.0 + 32;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is I get an error that says ''can't convert from double[] to double '' or something similar. (Edit: nvm I had to fix the method, thanks for the help though!)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return three values (avg, min, max) in a function by only writing "double", you should do "double[]", so you can return the same thing you get.
So this function would be :

```
public double[] convertToFah(double array[]){

    double[] fahValue;

    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++){
         fahValue[index] = (array[index] * 1.8) + 32; // this is what i found on the internet, as i didn't really get what you wrote
    }

    return fahValue;
}
```

Then for your months problem. If I am right, you want to get the minimum and maximum values of the temperature for the months. If it is so, then your functions are quite nicely made, there are just few errors.

Here are the functions corrected :

```
public double findMin(double array[]){

    double min = 999; // I set here the value to a high number to get a smaller one after

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {

        // if the value is smaller than the previous smallest
        if (array[index] < min){
            min = array[index];
        }
    }

    return min;
}


public double findMax(double array[]){

    double max = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] > max){
            max = array[index];
            // return max; <- delete this line, let the return after the for function
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

If you have more questions, either about what I have written either something else, don't hesitate to ask :)